# Print a Statement With There Privious And Next Value. SUNDAY MONDAY Program using PHP

Tags: php

I am building a program to print the statement using Switch Statement in PHP as per users's input.

Whenver any user input any number then i am printing a value.

This is my code.

```
if (isset($_POST['inputnumber'])) 
{
    fetchDays($_POST['inputnumber']);
}
```

This is my function which will print the data if any case matched.

```
function fetchDays($data)
{
    switch ($data) 
    {
        case 1:
            echo "Sunday";
            break;
        case 2:
            echo "Monday";
            break;
        case 3:
            echo "Tuesday";
            break;
        case 4:
            echo "Wedesday";
            break;
        case 5:
            echo "Thursday";
            break;
        case 6:
            echo "Friday";
            break;
        case 7:
            echo "Saturday";
            break;
        
        default:
            echo "Enter Valid Week Number";
            break;
    }
}
```

The question is that the how can I print the value with previous and next value,

Suppos if a user enter 2, I want to print the MONDAY with privious and next value.

for eg.

> SUNDAY MONDAY TUESDAY

If user enter 1, as per the condition I want to print value with there next value, because the privious value doesn't exist.
The same logic will be applied on the last input which is 7.

Comment: So echo previous and next days as well.

Comment: yeah, i can do this, but i don't want to use hard code

Comment: Well, the offset of previous and next days are just 1 and its fine if they are always going to remain 1

Comment: @nice_dev can you give me the answer

Comment: I meant like `echo 'SUNDAY MONDAY TUESDAY';` but now I am thinking of a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can call fetchDays mutiple times

```
if (isset($_POST['inputnumber'])) {
    $inputNumber = $_POST['inputnumber'];
    if ($inputNumber > 1 && $inputNumber <= 7) { 
        fetchDays($inputNumber - 1);
        echo ' ';
    }
    fetchDays($inputNumber);
    if ($inputNumber < 7 && $inputNumber >= 1) {
        echo ' ';
        fetchDays($inputNumber + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: nah this is not working, on 8 input printing the studay with invalid input

Comment: on 9 input printing te default value 2 times of switch statement

Answer (score 0):

Put the strings inside an array to make it concise and use `implode()` to stitch days together. You can improvise it with complex bit operations but that would make the code unreadable for something so simple.

So, increment week day by 1 if day given is 1 and decrement day by 1 if day given is 7. Now, implode() them starting from a day before with an offset of 3.

```
<?php

function fetchDays($week_day){
    if($week_day < 1 || $week_day > 7) return "Enter valid week number";
    $days = ["", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    if($week_day == 1) $week_day++;
    else if($week_day == 7) $week_day--;
    return implode(" ",array_slice($days,$week_day - 1,3));
}
```

**Driver Code:**

```
foreach(range(1,7) as $day){
    echo $day, " " ,fetchDays($day),PHP_EOL;
}
```